# UIScrollView as a means of navigation using a container UIViewController in iOS5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I've accomplished a similar setup to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961554/how-does-uiscrollview-work-with-storyboard-and-show-different-uiviewcontrollers)** stackoverflow challenge.

Except it seems to break the UIViewControllers, because they don't receive certain messages properly (eg. viewDidAppear)

Further research reveals that the solution rests in iOS5 by using some container UIViewControllers.

Has anyone accomplished this successfully with UIScrollView?
I watched the WWDC2011 video on it and it's still confusing me on how I exactly replace my UIScrollView:subviews with full UIViewControllers.  :/

Comment: the link you posted is broken

Comment: Fixed the link, and added my answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With enough persistence (aka. Googling), and some luck with timing, I solved this challenge by using [Tom Fewster's code ("Using UIPageControl as a container UIViewController")](http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168).

Thank you Tom.  :)

Comment: Yeah, but he is calling the view lifecycle methods manually... I thought the whole purpose of the UIViewController containment was so you didn't have to do this? I don't have an answer to this... but I'm going to explore a solution

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something along these lines a little while ago.

https://github.com/heardrwt/LayoutScrollView

It supports x number of views, as well as overlay views that allow for the tracking, addition and removal of on screen content.

it supports iOS4+ and uses iOS 5 containment when available.